# Get term name from term ID?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I cannot figure out how to get the taxonomy term name if I have the taxonomy term's ID.

This is my current code

```
// create a dropdown menu of the quantity taxonomy 
wp_dropdown_categories( 
    array('taxonomy' => 'quantity_category', 'name' => 'productQuantity', 'hide_empty' => 0)
); 

$quantityTerms = $_POST['productQuantity'];
$quantityTax   = 'quantity_category';
```

The value of `$quantityTerms` is not the "name" of the quantity but the ID of the quantity category. When it sets the object terms, it creates a new category called "ID#" and not inserting it into the category by name.

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $quantityTerms, $quantityTax, $append );
```

Comment: @JonFury, many of your questions demonstrate a complete lack of research effort - _you could have answered this question for yourself by [typing it's title into Google](http://bit.ly/Kl8JJq)_, not to mention that's it's answered in numerous other on-site questions that you would have seen had you searched WPSE. No one wants to waste their time answering questions that have been answered a hundred times before already. Please use a search engine, the WPSE search, and the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) before slapping questions on WPSE. Our community _is not_ a search engine.

Answer (score 25):

The function [get_term_by()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) would allow you to get the taxonomy term name from the id.

```
$quantityTermObject = get_term_by( 'id', absint( $quantityTerms ), 'quantity_category' );
$quantityTermName = $quantityTermObject->name;
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for you @JonFurry.